# Opening a drop-down menu popup on a div using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to toggle a drop-down on a div using twitter-bootstrap?

I currently have a bunch of divs on my page in the form of square menu items. If a square menu item div is clicked I would like a drop-down to show similar to the '[Button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns)' example on the bootstrap website.

**CODE:**
The code below is using an asp.net repeater. Basically everything in the ItemTemplate is dynamically generated on the server so you can look at it as a for-loop to generate my primary navigation items. I would like to make it so when one of these primary navigation items is clicked that a sub-menu shows. I don't care if it uses a popover or a drop-down, but I need something to show sub-items. Please disregard any templating syntax.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="primaryNav">                                  
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="primary-nav-item">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="navItem" runat="server" CssClass="mainNav-item-tile" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NavUrl") %>'>
                <img width="64" height="64" src='<%# Eval("ImgSrc") %>' class="primary-nav-item-tile-img" />
                <span><%# Eval("Title") %></span>
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul> 
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Yes you can. I don't know really where you are struggling at this moment? Can you provide some code?

Comment: @djl I updated it with some code. I basically would like to add some kind of nice sub-menu on the click of the li where class="primary-nav-item". So you can ignore the rest of the code.

Comment: So.. You want to click the `li`. I dont think that's possible without js.. Bootstrap uses a `button` or an `a` to handle this sort of situations. See this bit: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: I actually found a clean and simple way to do it using this technique: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp